Android Storage access framework с NIO
Как использовать Storage Access Framework с NIO 2? Меня интересует класс Files. Его методы требуют класс Path. Можно было бы использовать Paths.get(URI) , но тот требует java.net.URI , а SAF выдает android.net.URI. Paths.get(new java.net.URI(uri.toString()) тоже не работает.

SAF не даёт доступ к файлам, он даёт доступ к провайдеру документов и только через этот провайдер возможно с ними работать.

И что, прочитать его можно только используя inputStream из IO ?

Да, гугловский велосипед предполагает, что мы должны понимать документы не как локальные файлы, а как контент на сервере - то есть вот вам убогий REST API и мучайтесь с ним как хотите.
